# JAXB: 'xml:space' is undefined

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, docx

I want to serialize a docx file in Java.
Therefore I've downloaded the standardisation files for Office Open XML File Formats from [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) (ECMA-376 4th edition Part 1).

The downloaded zip includes xsd files (Subpackage: OfficeOpenXML-XMLSchema-Strict).

But when I try to generate Java files from the xsd files using the command

```
xjc wml.xsd -nv
```

I'm getting the following error:

> [ERROR] undefined attribute 'xml:space'

How is that even possible when it's standardised?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: This refers to the attribute @space in the http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace bound by definition to the prefix xml:. You might delete the references to this attribute for the time being and see whether you need it later on.